# Approximate solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any "approximate" solution for second order differential equation with time-dependent coefficients expressed by $\ddot x+a(t) \dot x+b(t)x+c(t)=0$?

In addition, if functions $a(t)$, $b(t)$ and $c(t)$ are bounded, how we can show the solution is bounded for $0<t<t_a$?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain approximate solutions using numerical methods. If what you want is an approximate formula in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$, there is none that I know of.

For the second question, write the equation as a two-dimensional system:
$$
x'=y,\quad y'= a\,y+b\,x+c.
$$
Let $(x,y)=Z$. Then the equation becomes $Z'=A\,Z+C$, where
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\b&a}\quad\text{and}\quad C=\pmatrix{0\\c}.
$$
Write the equation as an integral equation:
$$
Z=Z(0)+\int_0^t(A(s)\,Z(s)+C(s))\,ds.
$$
Using the boundedness of the coefficients you can get an inequality
$$
\|Z(s)\|\le M_1+M_2\int_0^t\|Z(s)\|\,ds
$$
for some constants $M_1$ and $M_2$. The result follows now from Gronwall's lemma.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful.